# How to sign a PDF and create PKCS#7 or CAdES detached container

Tags: java, pdfbox, amazon-cloudhsm

I need to sign a PDF using the PDFBox library and AWS CloudHSM. I tried to do it by following the next steps:

1. Insert data into a PDF
2. Calculate a PDF digest
3. Send the PDF digest to the AWS CloudHSM and sign it
4. Insert this signature into the PDF
   As a result, my PDF document hasn't been signed.
   The calculating PDF digest code:

```
public byte[] getDigest(byte[] pdf) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdf)) {
         // add signature dictionary
         ExternalSigningSupport externalSigningSupport = pdfDocument.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(out);
         byte[] dataToSign;
         try (final InputStream content = externalSigningSupport.getContent()) {
             dataToSign = IOUtils.toByteArray(content);
             final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256");
             return digest.digest(dataToSign);
         }
    }
}
```

Then I sent this digest to the AWS CloudHSM

```
public byte[] signViaHSM(byte[] pdfDigest) {
    if (Security.getProvider(CloudHsmProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null) {
         Security.addProvider(new CloudHsmProvider());
    }
    keyStore = KeyStoreWithAttributes.getInstance(CloudHsmProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    KeyAttributesMap keyAttributes = new KeyAttributesMap();
    keyAttributes.put(KeyAttribute.LABEL, aliasName);
    keyAttributes.put(KeyAttribute.OBJECT_CLASS, ObjectClassType.PRIVATE_KEY);
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(attributes);
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance(signingAlgorithm.toString(), CloudHsmProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    sig.initSign(privateKey);
    sig.update(documentBytes);
    return sig.sign();
}
```

Insert signature to the PDF

```
public void insertSignature(byte[] signature, ExternalSigningSupport signing) {
    ...
    signing.setSignature(signature)
}
```

Then I downloaded the PDF document, and this one is broken.
Can anyone help me insert the signature into the pkcs7 container and sign the PDF?
Where is my issue?
 What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: A PKCS#7 or CAdES style signature requires that you create a CMS signature container, not a mere naked signature. You can create such a signature container like it is done in the `sign` method of the PDFBox example `CreateSignatureBase` class, see [here](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateSignatureBase.java#L134).

Comment: @mkl Can you tell me about other certificates? If I have the ocsps and crl certificates this container also include these? Or do I need to process them manually and insert them into the CMS container? Sorry, maybe my question is rediculous, but I am new in the signing process.

Comment: Start simple, ignore complications (like OCSP or CRL revocation information) at first. The only certificate you need to start with is the signer certificate with the public key associated to your private key in the cloud HSM. As soon as that works, add the whole certificate path of that signer certificate. And only thereafter integrate revocation information. In particular you have to make sure you know which kind of PDF signature you need to support: Pure PAdES? Pure ISO 32000-1 legacy? a mix thereof?

Comment: @mkl thank you for trying to help me. I need to know more about signatures and cryptography because I don't know anything about the difference between containers PAdES or CAdES etc.

Comment: @mkl I think the PDFBox library creates these containers for signatures themselves, but as I see, I need to create it manually

Comment: *"I don't know anything about the difference between containers PAdES or CAdES etc."* - You create a PAdES PDF signature by embedding a specially profiled CAdES CMS signature container into the PDF. For details see ETSI EN 319 142 and ETSI EN 319 122.